# Missing header files from an shared C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

I have downloaded an .NET solution, which is contains 2 C# and 1 C++ project.
When I build the solution, the Error List says:

> Error  1   error C1083: **Cannot open include file: 'libavformat/avformat.h':** No such file or directory  C:\Users\Dinh\Downloads\TestOnvif-master\TestOnvif-master\FFmpegRTSPCppCLR\FFmpegMedia.cpp  19  1   TestFFmpegLib

Actually, I see an folder in solution directory named **lib**, it containts all *.h files that the C++ project need to use.

Som, How to make the C++ project see these *.h in the **lib** folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the project's property dialog.
Then go to: Configuration Properties - C/C++ - General - Additional Include Directories and add the path to the libavformat folder.